# Why is my game freezing?

Tags: unity, android, performance

Ok here is what I have done. I have made a simple test game where you move a character around. I built it and installed the app onto 2 different devices (as it will be a multiplayer game later).

*Phone1* - Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android version 4.4 kit kat I know I need to update it)

*Phone2* - LG G Stylo (Android version 5.1 lollipop)

My SDK - I have android 6.0 (API 23) installed everything up to date.

*Phone1* plays it flawlessly no errors. *Phone2* plays it until it freezes at random times. Not much going on in the scene as far as graphics. I kept it pretty simple.

Some debugging I did was to check the logcat. No errors are shown! The only thing I notice is that the frames just stop. So I go to developers options on both phones and check the box that allows you to see every update. I find out that after a while *Phone2* stops updating the games frames, which freezes it. It is no longer calling `Update()`. *Phone1* keeps running perfectly no crash yet.

What am I doing wrong? I am guessing it's a version issue but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Can you run your app with the debugger attached and break into the app when it freezes to see where it's stuck? We'll need more information than this. There's too many reasons an app could freeze like that: infinite loop, thread mutex, blocking io, ...

Comment: I have attached my device to the debugger. I type in something like this. adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG. I am getting nothing unusual however...besides it just stopping as if I pause the game

Comment: I noticed, however, when I am running the app and I hit the home button and then bring the app up again. It begins to update again for a little bit. After awhile it goes right back to 'pausing'.

Comment: Like I stated before all of this only happens with one of the phones. The other one doesn't freeze at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can try attaching MonoDevelop ( http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AttachingMonoDevelopDebuggerToAnAndroidDevice.html ) to your device and hope that it can break when the game freeze and tell you where the hang is but this does not always work.

If that does not work you're in for a good old session of "printf" debugging (in the case of unity it's Debug.Log() ) and hope that:

- the issue is somewhere surrounded by c# code
- not deep within a native plugin
- not within Unity
- that Debug.Log() does not change timing in a way that prevent the issue from happening making it impossible to narrow down the issue.

You're going to have to put Debug.Log() calls around parts of the code you suspect might hang and keep narrowing it down until you find the exact spot that hangs. (Yes, this is probably going to take a while.)

And make a backup of your project first, it'll be easier to revert the mess of Debug.Log() that will be added once the issue if found (hopefully).

For example:

```
void Update() {
    Debug.Log("MainHero Update() Begin");

    ... the hero code

    Debug.Log("MainHero Update() End");
}
```

And look at the log for a Begin without an End when it hangs, then once you find the function that hangs you can narrow it down by adding Debug.Log()s inside it between parts of the code.

You'll have to check every functions until you've found the line of code that causes these hangs.

Which may not even be in the C# code. It could be somewhere in a native thread such as the sound or networking.

Another thing you can try is remove Google Play and/or sound and/or anything else you can think of and keep going by elimination until it doesn't freeze anymore. (Again, make a backup of your project first.)

Comment: Ok I will go and dig more tthoroughly. Luckily I reached this error reeeaally early in development so I only have a few scripts running currently. Debug.Log() here I come....